Describing two levels of a spin 1 triplet with zero field splitting as an effective spin 1/2
I am working with NV centers and there one can describe the groundstate triplet of the system with a Hamiltonian of the form:
\begin{equation}
 H_e = D \hat{S_z}^2 + g \mu_B ( B_x \hat{S_x} + B_y \hat{S_y} + B_z \hat{S_z} ).
\end{equation}
with the Spin-1 operators $\hat{S_i}$ as defined here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(physics)#Higher_spins) as well as assuming a large static magnetic field in z-direction as well as weak ocillating magnetic fields in x and y one can get for the Hamiltonian:
\begin{equation}
\left[\begin{matrix}\omega_{0,+1} {\hbar} & \frac{\Omega_{R}}{2} {\hbar} e^{- i \omega_{mw} t} & 0 \\\ \frac{\Omega_{R}}{2} {\hbar} e^{i \omega_{mw} t} & 0 & \frac{\Omega_{R}}{2} {\hbar} e^{- i \omega_{mw} t} \\\ 0 & \frac{\Omega_{R}}{2} {\hbar} e^{i \omega_{mw} t} & \omega_{0,-1} {\hbar}\end{matrix}\right],
\end{equation}
where we assumed $B_x = B_1 cos(\omega_{mw} t)$ and $B_y = B_1 sin(\omega_{mw} t)$ as well as ${\hbar} \frac{\Omega_{R}}{2} = g \mu_B B_1$ and ${\hbar} \omega_{0,\pm 1} = D \pm g \mu_B B_z$.
For a large enough $B_z$, the states of +1 and -1 are split far enough in energy so that people just describe e.g. the 0 and -1 levels as an effective two-level subsystem ... but as I see it they usually just take the lower block of the Hamiltonian
\begin{equation}
\left[\begin{matrix}  0 & \frac{\Omega_{R}}{2} {\hbar} e^{- i \omega_{mw} t} \\\ \frac{\Omega_{R}}{2} {\hbar} e^{i \omega_{mw} t} & \omega_{0,-1} {\hbar}\end{matrix}\right],
\end{equation}and neglect that the Hamiltonian before was not Block diagonal. Is there a more formal way to justify this? E.g. a Transformation into some rotating frame and then applying e.g. a kind of rotating wave approximation or so? Could one do a Schriefer-Wolff Transformation for this (I heard of them in a lecture once but didnt quite understand how it works)?
Cheers and thanks in advance
